# Using string.Split() in AutoMapper while conversion

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, datamapper

I have two classes A and B and I am converting class A to B, and there's one property that is a string but has two date times within one string value.

```
class A 
{
    public string dates { get; set; }
}

class B: A
{
    public B()
    {
        Map(m=> m.dates)
            .TypeConverter<DateTimeConverter>()
            .TypeConverterOption.Format("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssz");
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I have one value in the dates, it's working perfectly, but when it's multiple values with a new line splitter, it gives the error.

- Working Fine on `2023-01-30T01:00:00`
  expected output: `2023-01-30T01:00:00z` (works as expected)
- An issue on `2023-01-30T01:00:00\r\n2023-01-30T01:00:00\r\n`
  Expected output: `2023-01-30T01:00:00z\r\n2023-01-30T01:00:00z\r\n`

Any solution?

Comment: Are you able to provide a bit more information? For example, what format do you want your output to take? Could go with an array of dates, another delimited string...etc. Would also be helpful to see more of your code.

Comment: The DateTimeConverter can't handle multiple dates separated by a newline. You'll have to write a custom converter and decide which value to use.

Comment: @swemoph I want to have a string as a output but string of formatted dates

Comment: @DavidLibido Can I mark a condition that if the string has one date, it would work with DateTimeConverter otherwise it would work with custom converter?

Comment: @ImranAhmadShahid Use always the custom converter that will split the string and use the DateTimeConverter on every date in the string.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use linq to split your string to and, out put it in any format that you want.

```
class A
{
    public string dates { get; set; } 
}
class B : A
{
    public B()
    {
        Map();
    }

    private void Map()
    {
        var ss = "2017-01-11T10:27:00\r\n2011-09-04T12:30:22\r\n2020-07-17T03:51:20";
        var n = ss.Length;

        var list = new List<string>();

        var sp = ss.Split('\n');

        sp.ToList().ForEach(x => list.Add(DateTime.Parse(x).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssz")));

        dates = string.Join("__", list.ToArray());
    }
}
```

if it is Windows the "\n" it is works as "\r\n" during splitting the string, the split() method takes argument type char, therefore you can not split it using two chars "\r\n" or string.
if it is Mac change the "\n" with "\r".